# Exclude/include regex patterns

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, regex-negation

I want to try to make some more types of regex, so I have been trying to make the following work.

Here is my expression: https://regex101.com/r/VzspFy/4/

On the test strings, the very first 3 are good, so patterns like that must be matched, the problem is the last one, which I don't want to be included, so I tried to do this:

https://regex101.com/r/9HVKTK/2

and this:

https://regex101.com/r/9HVKTK/1

But no luck!

The main idea is:

```
`aaa ... bbb ccc` -> must match
`ccc ... (aaa|ddd|eee) ... bbb ccc` -> should not match
```

How can I make it work or maybe some better implementation?

Comment: Try [`^(?:(?!\b(eng|ita)\b).)*\K\beng\W+\w+\W+sub\s?ita\b`](https://regex101.com/r/VzspFy/6)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I feel that OP needs to match a substring once if there is no specific substring before it.

Comment: So... basically, you want to match 'Eng xyz - Sub Ita', where `xyz` is some random three letters, right?

Comment: (Aside: note that Stack Overflow is not a chatroom, so "thx", "wanna" and "lol" are not appropriate here. Use real words please - a technical standard of writing is preferred).

Comment: @halfer Sorry about my language, my english is not so good, sometimes I try to explain myself in a best way I can. I always try to learn some.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution seems to works, to me is like an extraterrestrial language. Now I add some text to verify all possible case that came in my mind. For me is very strange the aproach, I've to read carefully your solution, I can't figure out why works in such a simple code. I think my aproac was "complicated"

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder Basically I think so, but must also not have any ita before the 'Eng xyz - Sub Ita'

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can I abuse of your experience? I found a patter that don't match, but must be. I tried here https://regex101.com/r/VzspFy/10 if you look the last line, don't match the pattern ENG.Sub.ITA I tried adding [A-Za-z_.-]? or [A-Za-z_.-]+ after the /K but don't work. Meantime I'm looking for a solution but I don't know why seems to be so complicate, in my mind is simple, need to capture also a dot.

Comment: I went to sleep unusually early yesterday and could not see your comments. So, 1) my solution from top comment does not work. 2) I thought you need to match `eng...sub...ita` if there were no `eng` or `ita` whole words before them. Do you want to match that chain of words only if `eng` or `ita` do not appear after start of string or after `]`? Try [`(?:^|])(?:(?!\b(?:eng|ita)\b)[^]])*\K\beng(?:\W+\w+)?\W+sub\W+ita\b`](https://regex101.com/r/VzspFy/15)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works great thanks, the only problem now is that the \K is not compatible with the .net with perl incapsulation

Comment: @JormanFranzini In .NET, it is even easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?:^|])(?:(?!\b(?:eng|ita)\b)[^]])*\b(eng(?:\W+\w+)?\W+sub\W+ita)\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VzspFy/17). You need to get Group 1 values.

**Pattern details**

- `(?:^|])` - either start of string or `]` (add `| RegexOptions.Multiline` if you have a multiline string as input, but I suppose these are all standalone strings)
- `(?:(?!\b(?:eng|ita)\b)[^]])*` - any char but `]`, as many as possible, that does not start a whole word `eng` or `ita` (see [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) to understand this construct better)
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(eng(?:\W+\w+)?\W+sub\W+ita)` - Group 1:

  - `eng` - a literal substring
  - `(?:\W+\w+)?` - an optional sequence of any 1+ non-word chars followed with 1+ word chars (actually, an optional word)
  - `\W+` - 1+ non-word chars
  - `sub` - a literal substring
  - `\W+` - 1+ non-word chars
  - `ita` - a literal substring
- `\b` - a word boundary

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/ZqBmeZ):

```
var strs = new List<string> { 
        "Lucifer S03e15 [XviD - Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita Eng] DLRip By Pir8 [CURA] Fede e Religioni",
        "Lucifer S03e15 [XviD - Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita Eng] DLRip By Pir8 [CURA] Fede e Religioni",
        "Lucifer S03e01-08 [XviD - Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita Eng] DLRip By Pir8 [CURA] Fede e Religioni SEASON PREMIERE",
        "Young Sheldon S01e13 [SATRip 720p - H264 - Eng Ac3 - Sub Ita] HDTV by AVS",
        "Young Sheldon S01e08 [Mux 1080p - H264 - Ita Eng Ac3 - Sub Ita Eng] WEBMux Morpheus",
        "Young Sheldon S01e08 [Mux 1080p - H264 - Ita Eng Ac3 - Sub Ita Eng] WEBMux Morpheus",
        "Young Sheldon S01e14 [SATRip 720p - H264 - Eng Ac3 - Sub Ita] HDTV by AVS",
        "Lucifer S03e15 [XviD - Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita Eng] DLRip By Pir8 [CURA] Fede e Religioni",
        "Lucifer S03e16 [XviD - Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita Eng] DLRip By Pir8 [CURA] Fede e Religioni",
        "Lucifer S02e01-13 [XviD - Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita] DLRip by Pir8 [CURA] Fede e Religioni FULL ",
        "Absentia S01e01-10 [Mux 1080p - H264 - Ita Eng Ac3 - Sub Ita Eng] By Morpheus The.Breadwinner.2017.ENG.Sub.ITA.HDRip.XviD-[WEB]"
    };
var rx = new Regex(@"(?:^|])(?:(?!\b(?:eng|ita)\b)[^]])*\b(eng(?:\W+\w+)?\W+sub\W+ita)\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (var s in strs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    var result = rx.Match(s);
    if (result.Success)
        Console.WriteLine("Matched: {0}", result.Groups[1].Value);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No match!");
    Console.WriteLine("==========================================");
}
```

Output:

```
Lucifer S03e15 [XviD - Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita Eng] DLRip By Pir8 [CURA] Fede e Religioni
Matched: Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita
==========================================
Lucifer S03e15 [XviD - Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita Eng] DLRip By Pir8 [CURA] Fede e Religioni
Matched: Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita
==========================================
Lucifer S03e01-08 [XviD - Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita Eng] DLRip By Pir8 [CURA] Fede e Religioni SEASON PREMIERE
Matched: Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita
==========================================
Young Sheldon S01e13 [SATRip 720p - H264 - Eng Ac3 - Sub Ita] HDTV by AVS
Matched: Eng Ac3 - Sub Ita
==========================================
Young Sheldon S01e08 [Mux 1080p - H264 - Ita Eng Ac3 - Sub Ita Eng] WEBMux Morpheus
No match!
==========================================
Young Sheldon S01e08 [Mux 1080p - H264 - Ita Eng Ac3 - Sub Ita Eng] WEBMux Morpheus
No match!
==========================================
Young Sheldon S01e14 [SATRip 720p - H264 - Eng Ac3 - Sub Ita] HDTV by AVS
Matched: Eng Ac3 - Sub Ita
==========================================
Lucifer S03e15 [XviD - Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita Eng] DLRip By Pir8 [CURA] Fede e Religioni
Matched: Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita
==========================================
Lucifer S03e16 [XviD - Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita Eng] DLRip By Pir8 [CURA] Fede e Religioni
Matched: Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita
==========================================
Lucifer S02e01-13 [XviD - Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita] DLRip by Pir8 [CURA] Fede e Religioni FULL 
Matched: Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita
==========================================
Absentia S01e01-10 [Mux 1080p - H264 - Ita Eng Ac3 - Sub Ita Eng] By Morpheus The.Breadwinner.2017.ENG.Sub.ITA.HDRip.XviD-[WEB]
Matched: ENG.Sub.ITA
==========================================
```

Comment: Impressive! Works also with the last I added. I'll search more extra example to test it out but seems to be very good. I've to read carefully the logic of the expression because for me is a kind of magic!

Comment: Hi, your solution seem the one that works best with all pattern. I'll try again in future, maybe will need some adjustment but I'm studying regex and I start to understand some, not like you but some

Comment: @JormanFranzini :) Why not like me? I am sure you are becoming a pro if you understand this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively simple regex for your problem:

```
(?:(?<=[-]\s)(?:ITA\s)?\w{3}\s\w{3}\s[-]\s\w{3}\s\w{3}\s\w{3}\b)|(?:Eng\.sub\.ita)
```

which you can [test out here](https://regex101.com/r/VzspFy/18).

### REGEX:

`(?<=[-]\s)` is a positive look-behind, that makes sure that the match is preceded by a dash and a space (but doesn't match them)

`(?:ITA\s)?` is a non-capturing group which tells the regex that if the match is preceded by an "ITA" and space, then match them also.

`\w{3}` matches a string of three word characters (letters/numbers/underscore or a combination of them)

`\s` means a single space, and

`[-]` is just a fancy way of matching a single `-`.

`|(?:Eng\.sub\.ita)` tells the regex to match `eng.sub.ita` (case-insensitive) along with the original matches if present in a sentence together.

### Do Note:

If the name of the show contains something along the lines of `- red SEO - two one` or 'dash-space-three_letters-space-three_letters-space-dash-space-three_letters-space-three_letters', then even the name of the show will be matched.

However, the likelihood of a show containing such a format is negligible, so you needn't worry about that.

Comment: Works this too, thank you, but don't match with this  Santa Clarita Diet S02e01 [Mux - XviD - Ita Eng Mp3 - Sub Ita Eng] NFMux By Pir8 [CURA]Mostri Nella Storia....     Is possible make it works with some extra char from start?

Comment: @JormanFranzini What do you mean it doesn't work? It does [over here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VzspFy/16)

Comment: @JormanFranzini Do you also want the eng part at the end of `... Sub Ita Eng`?

Comment: Hi, sorry I write wrong, I want to say that match! My bad! But don't have to match because this is ita eng ... sub ita eng. I think match because of XviD - Ita Eng ... the - make the difference, I think. In meantime I study all the code was writed here, so much to learn!

Comment: @JormanFranzini Don't worry about it. I have updated my code to fir your new conditions. Try it out :)

Comment: @JormanFranzini This new regex should match your needs now. Be sure to check it out. Also, if you feel that this answer has helped you, be sure to mark it as helpful, for further reference.

Comment: Tnx for you time and patience, but seems don't match all results, I don't know why, right now, but one that is the same to other don't match